# Showing nav dropdown when menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I like the Twitter bootstrap, but don't need all the features. In it though is a drop down function that I'm trying to replicate.

This is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul class="a">
        <li><a class="" href="">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="">Page 2</a></li>

        <li>
            <a class="" href="">Page 3</a>
            <ul class="drop_down">
                <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav_divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a class="" href="">Page 4</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href="">Page 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My javascript so far (it's not much):

```
$('nav.navigation li a').on('click', function() {
    if( $('nav.navigation li').has('ul.drop_down') ) {
        // Don't know how to add class to the clicked item,
        // and not all 'a' in the nav.
    }
});
```

Comment: Use Javascript fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('nav.navigation li a').on('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).parent().has('ul.drop_down')) {
        $(this).siblings('ul.drop_down').addClass("className");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Calling `e.preventDefault();` will prevent redirecting, because I don't think you'd want that when you only want to show the dropdown.

Comment: You are correct, and forgot to add the preventDefault into it cause I was going to do that later. In the `$(this).addClass("className");` it's adding the className to the `a` not the `ul`. Thoughts?

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv Oh I thought you want to add the class on the 'clicked item'. Anyway, I'll update my answer :)

Comment: if it's simply targeting the `ul` I can do that :]

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv Wait, where do you want to add the class? To the `a` in which the user clicks or to the `ul.drop_down`?

Comment: Brilliant, and clean. I added both your work into the one: http://jsfiddle.net/VzMgz/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('nav.navigation li a').on('click', function(event) {
    if( $('nav.navigation li').has('ul.drop_down') ) {
        // Don't know how to add class to the clicked item,
          alert(event.target.id); //here do stuff  with that id 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First it should be

```
$(function(){

  $('nav.navigation li a').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.parent('li').children('ul.drop_down').length ) {
        $this.addClass('someclass');
    }
  });

});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DAhZED?p=preview)